# Check what lab tests are missing for each subject, using a vector of the test names

Tags: r, missing-data

I'm doing a task for my clinical trial, I have a dataframe called LabData, that has upwards of 100 subjects. For each subject, there should have been 8 lab tests conducted. I have a vector of the test names and I'm trying to output a new dataframe that will tell me, for each subject, what tests are missing. I have used some dplyr as well as bracket notation, but stumped as to how to iterate through ever subject, and the hardest part being outputting everything into a clean dataframe.

Here is code for sample data

```
Tests <- data.frame(Tests=c("T1","T2","T3","T4","T5","T6","T7","T8"))

LabData= read.table(text=" Subject    Tests
SubjectA    T1
SubjectA    T2
SubjectA    T3
SubjectA    T4
SubjectA    T6
SubjectA    T7
SubjectA    T8
SubjectB    T2
SubjectB    T3
SubjectB    T4
SubjectB    T5
SubjectB    T6
SubjectB    T7
SubjectC    T1
SubjectC    T2
SubjectC    T3
SubjectC    T4
SubjectC    T5
SubjectC    T6
SubjectC    T7
SubjectC    T8 
", header=TRUE)
```

My ideal output would be this, simply telling me what subjects have which missing test. Again i have 100+ subjects so it would need to iterate through all of them

```
Subject  TestMiss

SubjectA   T5
SubjectB   T1
SubjectB   T8
```

I have tried something like these:

```
Missing <- data.frame(Tests$Tests[!Tests$Tests %in% LabData$Tests])
```

Also tried using tapply as i figured it would be the best way to loop through each subject, however no success with the way the current data is formatted. Any solution is much appreciated.

Comment: Converting from "long" to "wide" format gets you halfway there: `require(data.table); dcast(LabData, Subject ~ Tests)`. You can then find where you have missing data, e.g. `wide_LabData[, .(missing_trial=which(is.na(.SD))), by='Subject']`

Answer (score 1):

I would use `expand.grid` to provide all combinations and `mutate` a column with the result.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- expand.grid(
  Subject = unique(LabData$Subject),
  Tests = unique(LabData$Tests),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  ) %>%
  as_tibble %>%
  arrange(Subject, Tests) %>%
  mutate(
    TestMiss = !paste0(Subject, Tests) %in% paste0(LabData$Subject, LabData$Tests)
  )

df

# # A tibble: 24 x 3
#     Subject Tests TestMiss
#       <chr> <chr>    <lgl>
#  1 SubjectA    T1    FALSE
#  2 SubjectA    T2    FALSE
#  3 SubjectA    T3    FALSE
#  4 SubjectA    T4    FALSE
#  5 SubjectA    T5     TRUE
#  6 SubjectA    T6    FALSE
#  7 SubjectA    T7    FALSE
#  8 SubjectA    T8    FALSE
#  9 SubjectB    T1     TRUE
# 10 SubjectB    T2    FALSE
# # ... with 14 more rows
```

Then just `filter` where `TestMiss == TRUE` to get your final list.

```
df %>% filter(TestMiss == TRUE)

# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#    Subject Tests TestMiss
#      <chr> <chr>    <lgl>
# 1 SubjectA    T5     TRUE
# 2 SubjectB    T1     TRUE
# 3 SubjectB    T8     TRUE
```